# Validating timezone 'name' coming in from different site?

Tags: php, timezone

i've got users coming in from a different site and i'm getting that site to send across their timezone in a standard 'tz' format

```
 Antarctica/Casey    Antarctica/Davis   
 Antarctica/DumontDUrville  Antarctica/Macquarie 
 Antarctica/Mawson  Antarctica/McMurdo
```

How do i verify that this 'string' coming in is a VALID timezone entry?

---

this is what i'm doing

```
        $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
        if(!date_default_timezone_set($specifiedTimeZone))
        {
            date_default_timezone_set($script_tz);
            $errormessage = "Invalid TimeZone";
            return;         
        }
        date_default_timezone_set($script_tz);
```

but i dont like it - seems kludgy.

---

testing it out:

Test1

```
$test1 = 'America/New_York';
$test2 = 'junk';

$start = microtime(true);
for($i=1;$i<10000;$i++)
{
    if (in_array($test1, DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers())) {}else {}
    if (in_array($test2, DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers())) {}else {}
}

$end = microtime(true);

echo $end-$start;
?>

9.7208099365234
```

Test2

```
<?php

$test1 = 'America/New_York';
$test2 = 'junk';

error_reporting(0);
$start = microtime(true);
for($i=1;$i<10000;$i++)
{
        $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
        if(!date_default_timezone_set($test1))
        {
                date_default_timezone_set($script_tz);
        }
        else
                date_default_timezone_set($script_tz);
        $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
        if(!date_default_timezone_set($test2))
        {
                date_default_timezone_set($script_tz);
        }
        else
                date_default_timezone_set($script_tz);
}


$end = microtime(true);

echo $end-$start;
?>

0.25762510299683
```

Comment: Compare it with a list of valid timezones?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use [`DateTimeZone::listIdentifers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php)

```
if (in_array($timezone, DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers())) {
    echo "valid";
}
else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Comment: is the date_default_timezone_set() a bad approach / incorrect approach?

Comment: i like the listIdentifiers approach better, but it seems like its much slower

Comment: @Frank D if you are going to do it many times then you should set DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() to a variable... Running your tests again, using `$identifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()` I get 0.31013107299805 and 0.16420483589172

Comment: @Frank D also if you are running it many times, I would flip the array. `$identifiers = array_flip(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers())` and check `isset($indentifiers[$test1])`, that gets the time down to 0.0070869922637939

Comment: this is perfect. You link is dead. Here is an updated version - http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php

Comment: Why DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() does not return in its list "etc/UTC", but only "UTC", thus "etc/UTC" is considered invalid timezone?

Comment: This list is flawed. It lacks some timezones that are otherwise accepted by `date_default_timezone_set`, like `America/Montreal`

Answer (score 0):

Validate against the [tz database](http://cs.ucla.edu/~eggert/tz/tz-link.htm). There's http://code.google.com/p/tzdata/, that claims to provide the tz database in PHP format (whatever this means).

Comment: how do i do that in php "properly" - using standard php functions and/or approaches?

Comment: To answer that question, I would have to download the database, extract it, examine it and write some sample code. I suggest you try this yourself and come back when you have problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: [How to check is timezone identifier valid from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816960/how-to-check-is-timezone-identifier-valid-from-code)

Report different approaches to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper: `timezone_identifiers_list()` will return an array of strings of timezones. then you can use something like `in_array` to validate it.

```
if (in_array($timezone, timezone_identifiers_list())) {
    // valid
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could take the list of supported timezones, save it in a file and compare what you're getting to the list:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php