# How to check is timezone identifier valid from code?

Tags: php, validation, datetime, time, timezone

I'll try to explain what's the problem here.

According to [list of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) from PHP manual, I can see all valid TZ identifiers in PHP.

My first question is how to get that list from code but that's not what I really need.

My final goal is to write function `isValidTimezoneId()` that returns **TRUE** if timezone is valid, otherwise it should return **FALSE**.

```
function isValidTimezoneId($timezoneId) {
  # ...function body...
  return ?; # TRUE or FALSE
  }
```

So, when I pass TZ identifier using `$timezoneId` (string) in function I need boolean result.

Well, what I have so far...

### 1) Solution using @ operator

First solution I've got is something like this:

```
function isValidTimezoneId($timezoneId) {
  $savedZone = date_default_timezone_get(); # save current zone
  $res = $savedZone == $timezoneId; # it's TRUE if param matches current zone
  if (!$res) { # 0r...
    @date_default_timezone_set($timezoneId); # try to set new timezone
    $res = date_default_timezone_get() == $timezoneId; # it's true if new timezone set matches param string.
    }
  date_default_timezone_set($savedZone); # restore back old timezone
  return $res; # set result
  }
```

That works perfectly, but I want another solution (to avoid trying to set wrong timezone)

### 2) Solution using [timezone_identifiers_list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-identifiers-list.php)

Then, I was trying to get list of valid timezone identifiers and check it against parameter using [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function. So I've tried to use [timezone_identifiers_list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-identifiers-list.php), but that was not so good because a lot of timezones was missing in array returned by this function (alias of [DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php)). At first sight that was exactly what I was looking for.

```
function isValidTimezoneId($timezoneId) {
  $zoneList = timezone_identifiers_list(); # list of (all) valid timezones
  return in_array($timezoneId, $zoneList); # set result
  }
```

This code looks nice and easy but than I've found that `$zoneList` array contains ~400 elements. According to my calculations it should return 550+ elements. 150+ elements are missing... So that's not good enough as solution for my problem.

### 3) Solution based on [DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php)

This is last step on my way trying to find perfect solution. Using array returned by this method I can extract **all** timezone identifiers supported by PHP.

```
function createTZlist() {
  $tza = DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations();
  $tzlist = array();
  foreach ($tza as $zone)
    foreach ($zone as $item) 
      if (is_string($item['timezone_id']) && $item['timezone_id'] != '')
        $tzlist[] = $item['timezone_id'];
  $tzlist = array_unique($tzlist);
  asort($tzlist);
  return array_values($tzlist);
  }
```

This function returns 563 elements (in `Example #2` I've got **just 407**).

I've tried to find differences between those two arrays:

```
$a1 = timezone_identifiers_list();
$a2 = createTZlist();

print_r(array_values(array_diff($a2, $a1)));
```

Result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Africa/Asmera
    [1] => Africa/Timbuktu
    [2] => America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia
    [3] => America/Atka
    [4] => America/Buenos_Aires
    [5] => America/Catamarca
    [6] => America/Coral_Harbour
    [7] => America/Cordoba
    [8] => America/Ensenada
    [9] => America/Fort_Wayne
    [10] => America/Indianapolis
    [11] => America/Jujuy
    [12] => America/Knox_IN
    [13] => America/Louisville
    [14] => America/Mendoza
    [15] => America/Porto_Acre
    [16] => America/Rosario
    [17] => America/Virgin
    [18] => Asia/Ashkhabad
    [19] => Asia/Calcutta
    [20] => Asia/Chungking
    [21] => Asia/Dacca
    [22] => Asia/Istanbul
    [23] => Asia/Katmandu
    [24] => Asia/Macao
    [25] => Asia/Saigon
    [26] => Asia/Tel_Aviv
    [27] => Asia/Thimbu
    [28] => Asia/Ujung_Pandang
    [29] => Asia/Ulan_Bator
    [30] => Atlantic/Faeroe
    [31] => Atlantic/Jan_Mayen
    [32] => Australia/ACT
    [33] => Australia/Canberra
    [34] => Australia/LHI
    [35] => Australia/NSW
    [36] => Australia/North
    [37] => Australia/Queensland
    [38] => Australia/South
    [39] => Australia/Tasmania
    [40] => Australia/Victoria
    [41] => Australia/West
    [42] => Australia/Yancowinna
    [43] => Brazil/Acre
    [44] => Brazil/DeNoronha
    [45] => Brazil/East
    [46] => Brazil/West
    [47] => CET
    [48] => CST6CDT
    [49] => Canada/Atlantic
    [50] => Canada/Central
    [51] => Canada/East-Saskatchewan
    [52] => Canada/Eastern
    [53] => Canada/Mountain
    [54] => Canada/Newfoundland
    [55] => Canada/Pacific
    [56] => Canada/Saskatchewan
    [57] => Canada/Yukon
    [58] => Chile/Continental
    [59] => Chile/EasterIsland
    [60] => Cuba
    [61] => EET
    [62] => EST
    [63] => EST5EDT
    [64] => Egypt
    [65] => Eire
    [66] => Etc/GMT
    [67] => Etc/GMT+0
    [68] => Etc/GMT+1
    [69] => Etc/GMT+10
    [70] => Etc/GMT+11
    [71] => Etc/GMT+12
    [72] => Etc/GMT+2
    [73] => Etc/GMT+3
    [74] => Etc/GMT+4
    [75] => Etc/GMT+5
    [76] => Etc/GMT+6
    [77] => Etc/GMT+7
    [78] => Etc/GMT+8
    [79] => Etc/GMT+9
    [80] => Etc/GMT-0
    [81] => Etc/GMT-1
    [82] => Etc/GMT-10
    [83] => Etc/GMT-11
    [84] => Etc/GMT-12
    [85] => Etc/GMT-13
    [86] => Etc/GMT-14
    [87] => Etc/GMT-2
    [88] => Etc/GMT-3
    [89] => Etc/GMT-4
    [90] => Etc/GMT-5
    [91] => Etc/GMT-6
    [92] => Etc/GMT-7
    [93] => Etc/GMT-8
    [94] => Etc/GMT-9
    [95] => Etc/GMT0
    [96] => Etc/Greenwich
    [97] => Etc/UCT
    [98] => Etc/UTC
    [99] => Etc/Universal
    [100] => Etc/Zulu
    [101] => Europe/Belfast
    [102] => Europe/Nicosia
    [103] => Europe/Tiraspol
    [104] => Factory
    [105] => GB
    [106] => GB-Eire
    [107] => GMT
    [108] => GMT+0
    [109] => GMT-0
    [110] => GMT0
    [111] => Greenwich
    [112] => HST
    [113] => Hongkong
    [114] => Iceland
    [115] => Iran
    [116] => Israel
    [117] => Jamaica
    [118] => Japan
    [119] => Kwajalein
    [120] => Libya
    [121] => MET
    [122] => MST
    [123] => MST7MDT
    [124] => Mexico/BajaNorte
    [125] => Mexico/BajaSur
    [126] => Mexico/General
    [127] => NZ
    [128] => NZ-CHAT
    [129] => Navajo
    [130] => PRC
    [131] => PST8PDT
    [132] => Pacific/Ponape
    [133] => Pacific/Samoa
    [134] => Pacific/Truk
    [135] => Pacific/Yap
    [136] => Poland
    [137] => Portugal
    [138] => ROC
    [139] => ROK
    [140] => Singapore
    [141] => Turkey
    [142] => UCT
    [143] => US/Alaska
    [144] => US/Aleutian
    [145] => US/Arizona
    [146] => US/Central
    [147] => US/East-Indiana
    [148] => US/Eastern
    [149] => US/Hawaii
    [150] => US/Indiana-Starke
    [151] => US/Michigan
    [152] => US/Mountain
    [153] => US/Pacific
    [154] => US/Pacific-New
    [155] => US/Samoa
    [156] => Universal
    [157] => W-SU
    [158] => WET
    [159] => Zulu
)
```

This list contains all valid TZ identifiers that `Example #2` failed to match.

There's four TZ identifiers more (part of `$a1`):

```
print_r(array_values(array_diff($a1, $a2)));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => America/Bahia_Banderas
    [1] => Antarctica/Macquarie
    [2] => Pacific/Chuuk
    [3] => Pacific/Pohnpei
)
```

So now, I have almost perfect solution...

```
function isValidTimezoneId($timezoneId) {
  $zoneList = createTZlist(); # list of all valid timezones (last 4 are not included)
  return in_array($timezoneId, $zoneList); # set result
  }
```

That's my solution and I can use it. Of course, I use this function as part of class so I don't need to generate `$zoneList` on every methods call.

### What I really need here?

I'm wondering, is there any easier (quicker) solution to get list of all valid timezone identifiers as array (I want to avoid extracting that list from `DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations()` if that's possible)? Or if you know another way how to check **is timezone parameter valid**, please let me know (I repeat, `@` operator can't be part of solution).

---

P.S. If you need more details and examples, let me know. I guess you don't.

I'm using `PHP 5.3.5` (think that's not important).

---

### Update

Any part of code that throws exception on invalid timezone string (hidden using `@` or caught using `try..catch` block) is not solution I'm looking for.

---

### Another update

**I've put small bounty on this question!**

Now I'm looking for the easiest way how to extract list of **all** timezone identifiers in PHP array.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You solution works fine, so if it's speed you're looking for I would look more closely at what you're doing with your arrays. I've timed a few thousand trials to get reasonable average times, and these are the results:

```
createTZlist  : 20,713 microseconds per run
createTZlist2 : 13,848 microseconds per run
```

Here's the faster function:

```
function createTZList2()
{
 $out = array();
 $tza = timezone_abbreviations_list();
 foreach ($tza as $zone)
 {
  foreach ($zone as $item)
  {
   $out[$item['timezone_id']] = 1;
  }
 }
 unset($out['']);
 ksort($out);
 return array_keys($out);
}
```

The `if` test is faster if you reduce it to just `if ($item['timezone_id'])`, but rather than running it 489 times to catch a single case, it's quicker to unset the empty key afterwards.

Setting hash keys allows us the skip the `array_unique()` call which is more expensive. Sorting the keys and then extracting them is a tiny bit faster than extracting them and then sorting the extracted list.

If you drop the sorting (which is not needed unless you're comparing the list), it gets down to 12,339 microseconds.

But really, you don't need to return the keys anyway. Looking at the holistic `isValidTimezoneId()`, you'd be better off doing this:

```
function isValidTimezoneId2($tzid)
{
 $valid = array();
 $tza = timezone_abbreviations_list();
 foreach ($tza as $zone)
 {
  foreach ($zone as $item)
  {
   $valid[$item['timezone_id']] = true;
  }
 }
 unset($valid['']);
 return !!$valid[$tzid];
}
```

That is, assuming you only need to test once per execution, otherwise you'd want to save `$valid` after the first run. This approach avoids having to do a sort or converting the keys to values, key lookups are faster than in_array() searches and there's no extra function call. Setting the array values to `true` instead of `1` also removes a single cast when the result is true.

This brings it reliably down to under 12ms on my test machine, almost half the time of your example. A fun experiment in micro-optimizations!

Comment: +1 very interesting approach. Tell me one more thing. Which OS you have used to get those micro-times? Was that online server or localhost? Which PHP version? Have you used microtime() (with or without TRUE parameter)?

Comment: PHP 5.2.6 run from the command line, using an idle EC2 m1.small instance. I ran each trial 2000 times (in interleaved blocks of 100, to average out any other activity on the server affecting it), using microtime(true) to get the microseconds.

Comment: thanks, I'm just testing all 7 examples (mentioned in question+answers) using 3 different platforms (average microtime of 1,000,000 attempts).

Comment: This answer is mostly what I wanted to accomplish, even it's not perfect solution yet. I finally have finished tests. In next couple of days I'll update my question with results I've got. Thanks again man.

Comment: i know it's old, but small syntax error in your solution last line should return !!$valid (with a $)

Comment: I've tried this method using 'Antarctica/Davis' as a timezone and it returns an exception. This is a timezone that is returned via the \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() function. There are others that fail. But this one has popped up during testing and I started to debug. I cannot find a solution for all the identifiers..

Answer (score 40):

Why not use @ operator?
This code works pretty well, and you don't change default timezone:

```
function isValidTimezoneId($timezoneId) {
    @$tz=timezone_open($timezoneId);
    return $tz!==FALSE;
}
```

If you don't want @, you can do:

```
function isValidTimezoneId($timezoneId) {
    try{
        new DateTimeZone($timezoneId);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: The try-catch solution is best imho. Nice OO solution.

Comment: @hectorct - +1 for nice try. I really appreciate that. But... I don't want anything that throws exception! That's very important part of this task. Both examples are good but both of them can throw exception on invalid timezone (even it's hidden or caught). That's exactly what I want to avoid. I like both ways, thanks alot man.

Comment: @Wh1t3h4Ck5 Sorry, but can I ask why? Only wondering. Why do you look for such complex solutions when it can be achieved with a simple catch?

Comment: @hectorct - Course you can ask why? As you can see from my question, I already have couple of solutions to write working function. Actually I use that one with @ operator in my projects. Why? No special reason. That's probably related with my nature. I love to compare alias code in terms of speed. I'm kind of micro-time freak. Look [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556789/why-date-works-twice-as-fast-if-we-set-time-zone-from-code), that's exactly how I'm wasting my spare time ;) I'm always curious about code and how it works. This is just part of my curiosity.

Comment: @hectorct - Your first piece of code is something I was never thinking about. I totally forgot about DateTimeZone constructor. So that's something new for me and your answer is very usable, even that doesn't completely answer my question. However, thanks alot.

Comment: @Wh1t3h4Ck5 Thank you. I did a test and your code is 30 times faster than both of mine. Wow! I didn't know that trying to create the Timezone object was so expensive.

Comment: @hectorct, I've not tested it yet. But you're probably right. Classes are mostly based on native PHP functions and you never know how much of coding they contain in their constructor/methods. Every single line counts in terms of speed. Well, we're talking here about micro or nano seconds, but in huge code and especially in loops, that time multiplies.

Comment: Probably the `timezone_open`-based method is slower because it actually parses the timezone data for a successful result, while the other methods just grab a list of the valid identifiers without having to parse the actual timezone data. If you test it with invalid identifiers only, you may find the the `timezone_open`-based method to be faster (I did). The `timezone_open`-based method was also very sensitive to OS file caching in my testing; without a flush, the valid-zone speed dramatically improved on the second run. YMMV, of course, especially if you're on Windows rather than Linux.

Comment: DateTimeZone can also be constructed with UTC offsets. You can use `$tz->getLocation() !== false` to ensure it's a timezone and not an offset.

Answer (score 6):

When I tried this on a Linux system running 5.3.6, your Example #2 gave me 411 zones and Example #3 gave 496. The following slight modification to Example #2 gives me 591:

```
$zoneList = timezone_identifiers_list(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC);
```

There are no zones returned by Example #3 that are not returned with that modified Example #2.

On an OS X system running 5.3.3, Example #2 gives 407, Example #3 gives 564, and the modified Example #2 gives 565. Again, there are no zones returned by Example #3 that are not returned with that modified Example #2.

On a Linux system running 5.2.6 with the [timezonedb PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) installed, Example #2 gives me 571 zones and Example #3 gives me only 488. There are no zones returned by Example #3 that are not by Example #2 on this system. The constant DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC does not seem to exist in 5.2.6; it was probably added in 5.3.0.

So it seems the simplest way to get a list of all time zones in 5.3.x is 
`timezone_identifiers_list(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC)`, and in 5.2.x is `timezone_identifiers_list()`. The simplest (if not fastest) way to check if a particular string is a valid time zone is still probably `@timezone_open($timezoneId) !== false`.

Comment: +1, thanks, looks interesting. The fastest way is surely `@date_default_timezone_set($timezoneId)`, I know that because this method doesn't call class constructor like `@timezone_open($timezoneId)` (alias of `DateTimeZone::__construct()`). Actually, I did not test it yet but **hectorct** said in first answer that it's **30x** slower than my Example #1. However, I'm going to analyze and test your code later on different platforms. We'll see what kind of results I will got.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: As I mentioned above, it's more likely that the `timezone_open` method is slower for a successful result because it actually parses the timezone data while the other methods do not. If `date_default_timezone_set` is faster than `timezone_open`, I would guess it too just checks the identifier and doesn't bother to parse the timezone data until needed.

Comment: you're right... I guess that perfect solution will be if I can find how `date_default_timezone_set()` works (its body-code) so I can have quick solution without setting timezone. This line: `timezone_identifiers_list(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC)` looks like something I need (less coding than my Example #3 returns same result). I'm not home at the moment, so I'll compare results later and let you know is it what I'm looking for. I'm pretty sure it is.

Answer (score 1):

I would research what changes the perfect array and use a basic caching mechanism (like store the array in a file, that you include and update when needed). You're currently optimizing building an array that is static for 99.9999% of all the requests.

Edit:
Ok, static/dynamic.

```
if( !function_exists(timezone_version_get) )
{
    function timezone_version_get() { return '2009.6'; }
}
include 'tz_list_' . PHP_VERSION . '_' . timezone_version_get() . '.php';
```

Now each time the php version is updated, the file should be regenerated automatically by your code.

Comment: +1 Thanks Mel. I was thinking about that but I don't know which platform will use that code in the future. I can't bother updating that list (file or database records) every time it's changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux most if not all information on timezones there stored at `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`. You can walk over them using `is_file()` and related functions.

You can also parse the former files with `zdump` for codes or fetch [sources for these files](ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub/tzdata2011g.tar.gz)  and grep/cut out needed info. Again, you are not obliged to use built-in functions to accomplish the task. There isn't a rationale why would someone force you to use only the built-in date functions.

Comment: I'm on different platforms. I'm looking for ultimate solution for every platform. I don't want to use platform-specific way. However, this is nice answer. +1 Because there are no wrong answers on this question. Walking through the file(s) is to slow, especially in loops. Form me speed is my main goal. Thanks for your effort I appreciate that.

Comment: No one can stop you from walking over these file once and saving the results in any format you prefer for future use. Everything is in your hands here.

Answer (score 1):

1. See in PHP sources on [php_date.c](http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/ext/date/php_date.c) and [timezonemap.h](http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/ext/date/lib/timezonemap.h) that`s why I can say this is always in 101.111111% static info (but per php build).
2. If you want to get it dynamically, use timezone_abbreviations_list as DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations is a map to it.
3. As you can see all these values are just one time filled list for current PHP version.

So much faster solution is simple -- prepare somehow static file with retrieved ids one time per server **during install of your app** and use it.

For example:

```
function isValidTZ($zone) {
    static $zones = null;
    if (null === $zones) {
        include $YOUR_APP_STORAGE . '/tz_list.php';
    }
    // isset is muuuch faster than array_key_exists and also than in_array
    // so you should work with structure like [key => 1]
    return isset($zones[$zone]);
}
```

tz_list.php should be like this:

```
<?php
$zones = array(
    'Africa/Abidjan' => 1,
    'Africa/Accra' => 1,
    'Africa/Addis_Ababa' => 1,
    // ...
);
```

Comment: 1) Yeah it's static. I don't have source files in Windows distribution of PHP (just DLL-s). On linux servers I have not access to the source. 2) I already have that solution and guess that's not the perfect one, but at the moment I have not anything better. 3) Absolutely agree with you. Placing timezones in array is not what I need because I don't want to update this list for every PHP distribution. I'm working on ultimate solution for every PHP release and can't use something that depends of PHP version. However, nice answer +1.

Answer (score 1):

In case of php<5.3, how about this?

```
public static function is_valid_timezone($timezone)
{
    $now_timezone = @date_default_timezone_get();

    $result = @date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

    if( $now_timezone ){    
        // set back to current timezone
        date_default_timezone_set($now_timezone);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `1.` i cant choose version of PHP my clients use. `2.` Read the question first, `3.` read especially part under caption **What I really need here?** and line under example #1, `4.` this code doesn't look more simpler than one showed in example #2. Anyway, thanx for your try.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addendum to Cal's excellent answer.  I think the following might be even faster...

```
function isValidTimezoneID($tzid) {
    if (empty($tzid)) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach (timezone_abbreviations_list() as $zone) {
        foreach ($zone as $item) {
            if ($item["timezone_id"] == $tzid) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```